# How do I check if either or both of the two files exist?

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting

How can I check, in shell script, if *any* of two files exist?

It doesn't matter which of the two files exist or if they both exist.

Comment: You can find a lot of useful checks by reading `man test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if test -e file1 || test -e file2; then
  # At least one of file1 or file2 exists
  ...
else
  # Neither file1 nor file2 exists
fi
```

`test -e` checks for mere existence. You may want a more specific test, such as `-b` (exists and is block special), `-c` (exists and is character special), `-d` (exists and is a directory), `-f` (exists and is a regular file) etc.

Answer (score 4):

Both of the other answers run `test` twice.  While this will work, it has the inefficiency of two process forks.  You can get the "or" done in a single test with:

```
if [ -e file1 -o -e file2 ]; then ...
```

Which will be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

While `/bin/test` and the manual page for `test` does not name, it, you can use `test -a /path/to/file` to determine whether a file exists.

```
if [ -a file1 ] || [ -a file2 ]; then echo "I found something"; fi
```

`||` is effectively a logical OR.

Comment: What system has `-a` for exists?  The few I checked that I have access to all use `-e`

Comment: Bash built-in `test`.